# React Native image not showing or blank using Laravel Localhost source

Tags: react-native

I am trying to show images fetching from api. and to show images from localhost laravel project. Running my emulator on Genymotion. how do I do that?

Online images are working like fb fevicon. and I am not using the localhost:8000 link for images as I am testing on Genymotion

```
// URL to fetch apis
export const URL = 'http://10.0.3.2:8000';

// Showing/Displaying my image in React native
if(list && list.length > 0) {
    const listAfterPictures = list.map((item, index) => 
       <Image
          key={ index }
          source={{ uri: URL + index.image_name }}
          style={{ width: 300, height: 300 }}
       />
     );
     return (
      <View>
        {listAfterPictures}
      </View>
     )
}
```

I also tried to put width and height in source like:

```
<Image
 key={ index }
 source={{ uri: URL + index.image_name, width: 300, height: 300 }}
/>
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Is it maybe `uri: URL + item.image_name`  instead of `uri: URL + index.image_name` ?

Comment: Yes Tim. That was the issue. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please console log `URL + index.image_name` and check if all back slashes are there. And make sure to include the file extension e.g `.jpg` `.png`

Comment: yes thanks. fixed it. had a URL issue as Tim said `uri: URL + item.image_name` fixed it.